# Stop Skype from launching automatically after every update

Tags: windows-10, skype, updates

I currently have Skype 7.30.0.105 installed on Windows 10, but the option to launch at Windows startup in Skype settings is unchecked and it does not autostart normally, neither opening a window nor showing up in the system tray.

The annoying thing is that each time it updates itself, it launches anyway. Most annoying is that it isn't even polite enough to start in the background, minimized or in the system tray, no, it opens a foreground window that grabs the input focus, no matter what I'm doing currently.

This is not acceptable, especially as it mostly happens when I'm playing some real-time multiplayer online games in full screen mode. Those few seconds between Skype minimizing my game, loading its own window and me bing able to close it again and switch back often make me lose the game. Not to mention that this behaviour is very rude in any circumstance anyway.

So is there any way I can stop Skype from launching automatically after automatic updates? Alternatively, I'm also okay with stopping it from updating automatically unless the application was started manually by me.

Comment: Have you removed the start-up entry for Skype?  That way it never loads unless you start it yourself

Comment: It never loads on startup. It only launches after getting an update. @Ramhound

Comment: @Ramhound After investigating more closely, I found that although the main Skype application does not autostart, there is a Skype Updater service that runs automatically. I disabled this service now using the `msconfig` tool and will observe the issue...

Comment: To add to the comments, a faster, less intrusive alternative to the desktop version of Skype for Win10 systems is the "Skype Preview" app. That said, it probably lacks some features found in the former.